# Primefaces and tag value from bean method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I want to set the value of a primefaces tag from a bean method using arguments but this doesn't work.

On the Facelets page:

```
<p:outputLabel id="userLabel" value="#{languageBean.retrieveLanguage(1)}" />
<p:commandButton value="#{languageBean.retrieveLanguage(2)}" 
    action="#{loginBean.logIn()}"
    update="loginForm"/>
```

On the bean:

```
public String retrieveLanguage(int key) {
    return (String) getPageMap(pagePath, pageName).get(key);
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /components/login.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 24] Element type "p:outputLabel" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Could you give me any idea, please?

Regards,
 Roberto

Comment: for start try to rename it into `retrieveLanguage` (both in java and xhtml) , its a bad practice to call you assign your methods with `get` prefix

Comment: Thank you. I did it but is the same result.

Comment: does wrapping the numbers in `''` helps ? of course you'll have to apply additional changes on server side (int->String casting etc...) , also , do you have any other `<p:outputLabel` elements on your page ?

Comment: Is line 24 in this file really that `p:outputLabel` you shown? Didn't you maybe forgot to close " somewhere before?

Comment: If I use directly (out of any primefaces tag) the #{languageBean.retrieveLanguage(1)} the page is executed well. The problem is when I try to use it into a primefaces tag

Comment: @rvera, try the `h:outputLabel` instead

Comment: Are you using EL 2.2?

Comment: if you use <h:outputLabel> will get the value, I got the same problem, did you get it resolved??

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be passing in the language value from the front page - this is moving actual login from the app into the graphical frontend. Rather, store the language value in the bean and simply call retrieveLanguage.

If you are trying to handle translations, have a look at resource bundles instead.

Comment: Please answer the concrete problem as well instead of only making design recommendations which doesn't explain/answer the concrete question/problem at all. Otherwise better move on to a comment.